# LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_68.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, boost

I'm getting the above error while using `boost::filesystem`. I'm using Visual studio 15.

I've gone through other answers, and have checked that boost and program architecture is similar, path is correct. I've installed boost using `nuget`, so I'm pretty sure that the configurations are correct.

The header I've included is `<boost/filesystem.hpp`

The header boost headers I've included like : `<boost/circular_buffer.hpp`, compile and work fine. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you verify that the file is actually there? Have you added boosts lib directory to the path the linker searchs in the project settings for all configurations?

Comment: @Swordfish yes, I've mentioned the path in linker and additional #include directories. The `filesystem.hpp` file is present in the folder as well.

Comment: Is the lib file available on your system?

Comment: @Yuckfou I'm not talking bout the header, does `libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_68.lib` exist?

Comment: @Swordfish @CinCout No, `F:\VS_codes\ConsoleApplication2\packages\boost.1.68.0.0\lib\native\include\boost\filesystem` folder only has `.hpp files`. How do get the lib file?

Comment: @Yuckfou That's the wrong place to look, library files are not in the include folder.

Comment: @john where should I look then? I've searched the whole boost folder. There isn't even one .lib file

Comment: @Yuckfou There's two possibilities 1) nuget installed them somewhere completely different, 2) you have to build them yourself. My money is on 2, see here https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Comment: @Yuckfou FYI, most boost libraries are header only, so you don't need a library file, but filesystem is one that does need a library, and generally the procedure is that you build the libraries, for your architecture, yourself after you've downloaded. I'm guessing nuget has just done the download part for you.

Comment: @john "I'm guessing nuget has just down the download part for you." I just checked. That version that comes from nuget is only headers. No build system. So Yuckfou will have to download the real thing from [boost.org](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#get-boost)

Comment: And, referring to @John's list, (2) is a far better option, in case your compiler settings are different from that of a canned build. Yes, building Boost is a learning curve, but well worth the bother.

Comment: @john Thanks for the help, really appreciate it! I found where nuget has kept boost. All files are in .dll format. I'll just remove nuget package and build the one from boost's official site.

Comment: Just as a suggestion: because you are using VS2017, you may want to use <experimental/filesystem> or <filesystem> (C++17 standard) that are now included in VC++2017 (depending on your exact version), so you may not need boost.filesystem.